# p method in Ruby hard to search for

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm trying to find info on the `p` method in Ruby. It seems to produce internal info on the properties of a class but when I try to search for it I get every word that has the letter "p" in it.

Answer (score 13):

Have you seen the api doc page? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p

There's also http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/p

Comment: Cool. I didn't know it was in the Kernel. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Each method you can call "directly", e.g: print, p, abort, puts, readline, etc., is located in the Kernel class.

```
(Kernel.methods - Object.methods).sort.each do |method|
   puts method
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find more information about the `p` method from the Ruby documentation of the Kernel module:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p

> p(obj) → obj
>
> p(obj1, obj2, ...) → [obj, ...]
>
> p() → nil
>
> For each object, directly writes obj.inspect followed by a newline to
>   the program’s standard output.
>
> ```
> S = Struct.new(:name, :state)
> s = S['dave', 'TX']
> p s
> ```
>
> produces:
>
> ```
> #<S name="dave", state="TX">
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like:

`ri Kernel#p`

Comment: Cool. Didn't know you could do that. Thanks.